# Java - get parent process

Tags: java, process

I think Java doesn't provide much in their API about getting processes, is there a way that you could get a parent's process PID/ID in Java?

Comment: Not unless you use JNI or JNA.  JNA is pretty easy integrate to Java program: https://github.com/malyn/jnaplatext/blob/master/src/main/java/com/michaelalynmiller/jnaplatext/win32/ProcessUtils.java

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Linux you can check [procfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) using /proc/self/stat.

Comment: It's mostly running on Windows.

Comment: In that case it looks like you have to run some native code. Sorry.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your solution still. Others might find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Following from @Imz's answer, on Linux, grab the output of `/proc/self/stat` (it's a one-line file, so just read it like a normal file)

> 43732 (java) S **43725** 43725 11210 34822 43725 4202496 127791 387073
>   4055 0 3188 79 4597 253 20 0 53 0 16217706 39231705088 188764
>   18446744073709551615 4194304 4196452 140735605394256 140735605376816
>   274479481597 0 0 2 16800973 18446744073709551615 0 0 17 13 0 0 0 0 0

The 4th field (in bold above) is your *parent* process id